# How to get an entry's position from a complex query using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I want to know a player's position (rank) from a leaderboard. I'm not having a leaderboard table, it's being generated from the `users` table and a query. This is how I get the entries:

```
SELECT
   u.id as userId,
   u.xp as xp,
   u.nickname as nickname,
   SUM(opr.games_won) as wonGames,
   SUM(opr.games_lost) as lostGames 
FROM
   users u 
   INNER JOIN
      opponent_player_result opr ON u.id = opr.user_id 
WHERE
   u.last_login >= 1548374400000 
   AND u.xp > 0 
   AND u.zone_id = 1 
GROUP BY
   u.id 
ORDER BY
   u.xp DESC,
   wonGames DESC,
   lostGames ASC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

The `xp` column is for storing the player's experience points. After every game play this column in updated.

The `opponent_player_result` is a separated table where I keep the player's played game result:

```
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| id | games_lost | games_won | opponent_player | user_id |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------+---------+
|  1 |          3 |         0 |               0 |       1 |
|  2 |          2 |         1 |               1 |       1 |
|  3 |          0 |         3 |               2 |       1 |
|  4 |          4 |         2 |               0 |       2 |
|  5 |          0 |         1 |               1 |       2 |
|  6 |          1 |         1 |               2 |       2 |
|  7 |          2 |         3 |               0 |       3 |
|  8 |          3 |         0 |               1 |       3 |
|  9 |          3 |         4 |               2 |       3 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------+---------+
```

As you may have noticed, each player are having 3 opponent player result (because there are only 3 bots which the player can play).

The above query would give me the following result:

```
+--------+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| userId | xp | nickname | wonGames | lostGames |
+--------+----+----------+----------+-----------+
|      1 | 34 | nick1    |        4 |         5 |
|      3 | 29 | nick3    |        7 |         8 |
|      2 | 29 | nick2    |        4 |         5 |
+--------+----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

I'm not using MySQL `RANK()` functions, neither I'm not incrementing variables to associate the players positions (maybe that's what I should do).

**How to get a single player's position from the above leaderboard result?**

For example, user with `#id 3` would have rank `2`.

This is the query that I'm working on to find a player's position within the leaderboard:

```
SELECT u.id AS userId,
       u.xp AS xp,
       1 +
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM
     (SELECT SUM(opr.games_won) AS wonGames,
             SUM(opr.games_lost) AS lostGames
      FROM users AS p
      INNER JOIN opponent_player_result AS opr ON p.id = opr.user_id
      WHERE p.last_login >= 1548374400000
        AND p.xp > 0
        AND p.xp > u.xp
        AND p.zone_id = 1
      GROUP BY p.id
      ORDER BY p.xp DESC, wonGames DESC, lostGames ASC) AS counter) AS ranking
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.id = 1;
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'u.xp' in 'where clause'

As far I know, MySQL allows only 1 level deep nested or subquery, but in my example I am 3 level deep. But how do I reference then from the subquery to the outer query?

**Is this the right approach to get the leaderboard? Should I create a separated table and update it periodically?** I am very afraid of performance hit.

I'm using MySQL 8.0 version.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using ? `RANK()` is available in 8.0.

Comment: @GMB I am using MySQL 8.0 version.

Comment: *"maybe that's what I should do"*: Yes, you should use `RANK()`. I would suggest you would have a go at it, and if you still have a question, come back with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straightforward using ranking functions of MySQL 8.0. For example, [`DENSE_RANK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) computes the ranking of each row within a partition (tied records are assigned the same rank).

```
SELECT
   u.id as userId,
   u.xp as xp,
   u.nickname as nickname,
   SUM(opr.games_won) as wonGames,
   SUM(opr.games_lost) as lostGames,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY u.xp DESC) rnk
FROM
   users u 
   INNER JOIN
      opponent_player_result opr ON u.id = opr.user_id 
WHERE
   u.last_login >= 1548374400000 
   AND u.xp > 0 
   AND u.zone_id = 1 
GROUP BY
   u.id, u.xp, u.nickname
ORDER BY
   u.xp DESC,
   wonGames DESC,
   lostGames ASC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cA1kfVTdzaT1XL5jD1hNuq/2)** :

```
| userId | xp  | nickname | wonGames | lostGames | rnk |
| ------ | --- | -------- | -------- | --------- | --- |
| 1      | 34  | nick1    | 4        | 5         | 1   |
| 3      | 29  | nick3    | 7        | 8         | 2   |
| 2      | 29  | nick2    | 4        | 5         | 2   |
```

Comment: @GMB it's working for listing the whole table, but how to get for a single player only?

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian : for that one solution would be to wrap the above query like : `SELECT x.* FROM (<above query>) x WHERE x.userId = ?`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : thank you very much friend ! Much appreciate your comment.

Comment: @GMB - I have wrapped it and it seems to be working. Thank you! What have I done is that I have removed the `INNER JOIN` and placed the `won_games` and `lost_games` in the `users` table. I've changed the query `DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY u.xp DESC, u.won_gamesc DESC, u.lost_games ASC) rnk`. Should I remove the `ORDER BY u.xp, wonGames DESC, lostGames ASC` from the main query?